# opencart controller changes are being ignored

Tags: php, apache, xampp, opencart2.x

I am using opencart v2.3.0.2 on a xampp(win7) installation.

When I change some code in an opencart controller, these changes are being ignored.

I believe the old controller code is still in the cache.

How can I clear or deactivate the apachePHP/opencart cache or is the problem somewhere else?

I commented the caching module in my httpd.conf

```
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

but it changed nothing.

Comment: Please Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system & then check it site.

Comment: It works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner)

> [HDP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1923139/hdp)'s answer, but I think, it should be posted here